# NodeJS HTTP/2 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, http2

I am attempting to implement HTTP/2 on a node server using molnarg's [node-http2](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2) module. My original server.js works fine and when I implemented the HTTP/2 module I get a

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

from the browser (using Chrome on a ChromeBook).

**List of changes to implement HTTP/2:**

1. Created the cert & key .perm's
2. Changed the `hostPort` var in the config.json to 443 (tried w/80, 8000)
3. Add to server.js:

   `var certs = {key: fs.readFileSync('../../key.pem'),cert: fs.readFileSync('../../cert.pem')};`
4. Edit  server.js

   `require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {...}`

   to

   `require('http2').createServer(certs, function (request, response) {...}`

What am I missing or have wrong (I get no errors in the log)?

**Below is a copy of the server.js**

```
var environment = '../env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV;

// Process User config
var fS = require('fs')
  , jsonFile = fS.readFileSync(environment + '/config.json'), jsonString, hostIp, hostPort, cacheExp, cps;

try {
  jsonString              = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  var SERV_HOST           = jsonString['hostIp']
    , SERV_PORT           = jsonString['hostPort']
    , CACHE_EXP           = jsonString['cacheExp']
    , CPS                 = jsonString['cps']
    , xPowerBy            = ''
    , xFrameOptions       = ''
    , xXSSProtection      = ''
    , xContentTypeOption  = ''
    , cacheControl        = '';
} catch (err) {
  console.log('There is an error parsing the json file : ' + err);
}

// Load required modules
var web       = require('node-static')
  , watch     = require('staticsmith-watch')
  , fs        = require("fs");

var certs = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

// Load security setings via config.json
var security  =
    [{
      // Just some security stuff here
    }];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {

  var options = { host:   SERV_HOST
                , port:   SERV_PORT
                , cache:  CACHE_EXP
  };

  var public_dir = new web.Server(environment, options);

  // Serve it up!
  require('http2').createServer(certs, function (request, response) {
  // OLD 
  // require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {

    // Add Content Security Rules
    for(var i = 0; i < security.length; i++){
        response.setHeader(security[i].name, security[i].option);
      }

    request.addListener('end', function () {

        public_dir.serve(request, response, function (err, result) {
            if (err) { // There was an error serving the file
                console.error("Error serving " + request.url + " - " + err.message);
                // Respond to the client
                response.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
                response.end();
            }
        });
    }).resume();
  }).listen(options.port, options.host);

  console.log("serving at http://" + options.host + ":" + options.port);
  console.log("On Node v" + process.versions.node);

  watch({
    pattern:    '**/*',
    livereload: true,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of [node-spdy](https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy) was used in lieu of node-http2 because this module you can create HTTP2 / SPDY servers in node.js with natural http module interface and fallbacks to regular https (for browsers that don't support neither HTTP2, nor SPDY yet).

**The [above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34007870/742030) server.js now implementing the new module:**

```
var environment = '../env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV;

// Process User config
var fS = require('fs')
  , jsonFile = fS.readFileSync(environment + '/config.json'), jsonString, hostIp, hostPort, cacheExp, cps;

try {
  jsonString              = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  var SERV_HOST           = jsonString['hostIp']
    , SERV_PORT           = jsonString['hostPort']
    , CACHE_EXP           = jsonString['cacheExp']
    , CPS                 = jsonString['cps']
    , xPowerBy            = ':P'
    , xFrameOptions       = ''
    , xXSSProtection      = ''
    , xContentTypeOption  = ''
    , cacheControl        = '';
} catch (err) {
  console.log('There is an error parsing the json file : ' + err);
}

// Load required modules
var fs    = require('fs')
  , web   = require('node-static');

var public_dir = new web.Server(environment + '/_public');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(environment + '/keys/key.pem')
  , cert: fs.readFileSync(environment + '/keys/cert.pem')

  // SPDY-specific options 
  , spdy: {
      protocols: [ 'h2','spdy/3.1', 'spdy/3', 'spdy/2','http/1.1', 'http/1.0' ],
      plain: false,

      connection: {
        windowSize: 1024 * 1024, // Server's window size 

        // **optional** if true - server will send 3.1 frames on 3.0 *plain* spdy 
        autoSpdy31: false
      }
    }

  , host:   SERV_HOST
  , port:   SERV_PORT
  , cache:  CACHE_EXP

};

// Load security setings via config.json
var security  = [
    { name:   'X-Powered-By',
      option: xPowerBy }
  , { name:   'x-frame-options',
      option: xFrameOptions }
  , { name:   'X-XSS-Protection',
      option: xXSSProtection }
  , { name:   'X-Content-Type-Options',
      option: xContentTypeOption }
  , { name:   'Cache-Control',
      option: CACHE_EXP }
  , { name:   'Content-Security-Policy',
      option: CPS }
  , { name:   'server',
      option: 'Who knows' }
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {

  require("spdy").createServer(options, function(req, res) {

    // Add Content Security Rules
    for(var i = 0; i < security.length; i++){
      res.setHeader(security[i].name, security[i].option);
    }

    public_dir.serve(req, res, function (err, result) {
      if (err) { // There was an error serving the file
        console.error("Error serving " + req.url + " - " + err.message);
        // Respond to the client
        res.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
        res.end();
      }
    });
  }).listen(options.port, options.host);
  console.log("serving at https://" + options.host + ":" + options.port);
  console.log("On Node v" + process.versions.node);
}
```

This worked out of the box.